# Finish() isn't closing my second Activity, OnBackPressed() breaks the app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, activity-finish

From the MainActivity I open a new Activity like this

```
 val intent = Intent(context, ExerciseCatalogueActivity::class.java)
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE)
```

Then I have a clickListener call a method within my second activity

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            exerciseClickListener.exerciseIsClicked(currentExercise)
        }
```

Finally I try to pass the currentExercise to the MainActivity and finish the Second Activity like this

```
override fun exerciseIsClicked(exercise: Exercise) {
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, Intent().apply{ putExtra("key", exercise) })

        finish()
    }
```

Unfortunately nothing happens, until I press the back button which finishes the second activity. If I do it programatically with `onBackPressed`, I get an error `Fragment host is destroyed`

Comment: I'm not certain but I think that `activityForResult()` will be automatically destroyed when the result is returned to the main activity so you don't have to call `finish()`

Comment: Have you implemented & override `onActivityResult()` method in the MainActivity?

Comment: Yes I have implemented and overriden `onActivityResult()` in the recyclerview adapter in the main activity

Comment: @AlexPetev why did you put it in the adapter? Put it in the Activity. The method `onActivityResult()` should be in the Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You've already started `ExerciseCatalogueActivity` like this:

```
val intent = Intent(context, ExerciseCatalogueActivity::class.java)
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE)
```

Now, in your second activity (`ExerciseCatalogueActivity`), send the data like this:

```
val result = Intent()
result.putExtra("key", exercise)
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result)
finish()
```

Then, handle the result in your `MainActivity` like this:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val task = data?.getStringExtra("key")
            task?.let {
                 //Do something here with the returned value
            }
    }
}
```